# YII: Converting data format before CRUD?

Tags: php, date, yii, date-formatting

I have an input that accept a data in this format mm/dd/yyyy.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('purchase_date', 'type', 'type' => 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a date, try this formate -> (mm/dd/yyyy) !', 'dateFormat' => 'MM/dd/yyyy'),

);
}
```

however, the question is, how do I change the format to  YYYY-MM-DD after I capture it from the input
in order to put it into the database with this format YYYY-MM-DD.

example... user input the date in mm/dd/yyyy
I somehow convert it to YYYY-MM-DD before I save the model.

Comment: You can use a [`filter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh13) validation rule and write a function to convert from one format to the other.

Comment: Thank you, it would be great if there is an example, I looked at the filter in the link you provided but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `beforeSave`  function in your model and add logic to convert date format

```
public function beforeSave(){

    $this->purchase_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->purchase_date));
    return true;
}
```